# Javascript not importing npm package installed from git

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a package in my dependencies in `package.json` of npm. I have included the package from github in following way-

```
"dependencies": {
    "@aeternity/aepp-components": "git+https://git@github.com/aeternity/aepp-components.git#feature/v3",`
}
```

When I run `npm install`, everything installs, and I can see the module in `node_modules` folder. However when I try to `import`, and `run`, npm gives an error saying

```
dependancy not found
To install it, you can run: npm install --save aepp-components
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Edit: Snippet I used to import:

```
import AeButton from 'aepp-components'
```

Comment: How are you importing it. Provide the code snippet of that.

Comment: Did you do `npm install` after including it in your `package.json`?

Comment: Probably it is not compiled. Check path in the property main in the dependency's package.json. Then try to find the corresponding file. Does it exists?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal please see the edited question.

Comment: @yaswanth Yes I did `npm install`
@Drag13 Yes it exists

Comment: @ShubhamChaudhary check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do

```
import { AeButton } from '@aeternity/aepp-components'
```

see that how `AeButton` is imported using destructuring. And `@aeternity` specifies the default root source for the files and helps you map your file imports to it. Use that and it will work. You can also have a look at here in the [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aeternity/aepp-components#installation--usage)

Comment: you could explain to him why you changed the import from, and what @ is. This will make your answer way more complete

Comment: @MatheusSilva added

Answer (score 0):

When you have `@something/package-name`, this is the name of the entire package, you have to import using this full name. Now, why?

This is called a scoped package, and `@something` is the scope of that package. You can check more about scoped packages [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/scoped-packages).

Some packages exports items/components/whatever inside an object, which requires you to use the destructuring method. You can only be sure how it is imported if you look at the docs, otherwise you would need to deep into the codebase.